# Why does searching for characters work only at the end of the search string and not at the start?

Tags: regex, string, search, ksh

I initially wanted to search through a file and find lines which exactly match a search string. So I used this in my script:

```
grep -E ^"${sSearchString}"$ <file name>
```

where `^` and `$` mark the start and end of the line respectively.

Then I realised the row might contain leading or trailing spaces. To ignore the trailing spaces, I changed the code to:

```
grep -E ^"${sSearchString}*( )"$ <file name>
```

which again worked fine<sup>1</sup>.

However, this did not work for *leading* spaces:

```
grep -E ^"*( )${sSearchString}*( )"$ <file name>
```

Running this (from a command line, so like this: `grep -E ^"*( )<search string>*( )"$ <file name>`) gives me this error:

```
grep: RE error in ^*( )search string*( )$ ?, *, +, or { } not preceded by valid regular expression
```

Why does `*( )` fail before the search string but work after?

<sub>1 Though replacing `*( )` with `*(\s)` did not return anything. Any ideas why not?</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. It should be `( )*`, not `*( )`.

```
grep -E ^"( )*${sSearchString}( )*"$ <file name>
```

Also, if you want to ignore tabs and newlines too, use `\s*`.

Comment: Thanks - I got the syntax from [here](http://honglus.blogspot.nl/2010/03/regular-expression-in-condition.html) so it is strange that it is the wrong way around. But that fixed it, thank you. However the `\s*` does not work - nor does eg `(\s)*`

Answer (score 1):

It works at the end because the repeat is for `g` and not for `( )`.

It fails in the beginning because there is nothing to repeat.

Comment: I thought the repeat is for the bracket contents, this is what I read [here](http://honglus.blogspot.nl/2010/03/regular-expression-in-condition.html): `*(pattern-list)`

Comment: @Wikis Woah, that page is ***completely*** wrong. Don't use that. Try http://regular-expressions.info.